# how to disable orientation change rotation animation in react native

Tags: react-native

I need to disable the animation and then enable it again that plays when the orientation changes in react native.

the same like instant orientation change, what should I do?

thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you checked out https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation ? This should work for you.

Comment: that doesnt really help. its still animated

Comment: I'm looking to do this also, any solution?